# laravel controller not detected

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I got a laravel proyect, but when i run `php artisan route:list` thows this error:

```
 ReflectionException

  Class "CuboController" does not exist

  at C:\Users\ricar\dev\SistemaCubosLS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand.php:234
    230▕             if ($this->isFrameworkController($route)) {
    231▕                 return false;
    232▕             }
    233▕
  ➜ 234▕             $path = (new ReflectionClass($route->getControllerClass()))
    235▕                                 ->getFileName();
    236▕         } else {
    237▕             return false;
    238▕         }

  1   C:\Users\ricar\dev\SistemaCubosLS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand.php:234
      ReflectionClass::__construct()

  2   C:\Users\ricar\dev\SistemaCubosLS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand.php:156
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::isVendorRoute()
```

The strange thing is that when i start the server with `php artisan serve` it works perfectly in my machine, but when i try to acces in the ubuntu server does not let me in, throws a 404 error.

The controller exists, and like i said, in local works perfect, but in the apache server throws a 404 error.

What can it be and how can i fix it?

Comment: is the filename for the controller `CuboController.php`? and the class inside it is defined as `CuboController`? also what is the path to this controller and how did you define your route? what operating system is your local machine running?

Comment: @lagbox yes, the filename is `CuboController.php`, and is in the path `/app/Http/Controllers/CuboController.php`, The start of the file is: `class CuboController extends Controller{}`

Comment: HAve you tried `php artisan optimize:clear` or `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: did you add `use App\....CuboController.php` at the top?

Comment: Post what you have in your code.

Comment: you might need to run `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in one route the controller was calling the function with an "@", idk excacly why, but chaging that line with just the name of the function solved the issue.

Thank you everyone for your answers

the code changed was:

```
Route::put('/cubo/{cubo}', 'CuboController@update')->name('cubo.update');
```

for

```
Route::put('/cubo/{cubo}', 'update')->name('cubo.update');
```

Answer (score 1):

dont forget use this in your route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CuboController;
```

if it says 404, try to check `php artisan route:list`. If it not shown, try `php artisan optimize`

Mr. Kenneth has explained a lot for you in comment section.